# Sepreating python code in raspberry pi pico

Tags: python, import, raspberry-pi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am unable to import class from a different file in micro python on raspberry pi pico.

Eg.
directory structure

dir/ 
  |__main.py
  |__imports/
     |_example.py

filename : main.py

```py
from imports.example import ex

a = ex("name")
a.print_name()
```

filename : example.py

```py
class ex:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

The error states as following

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'imports.example'
```

The code works when all the classes are present inside the same file. I am using pico-go vscode extension on debain. I tried adding __ init __.py in the example directory, but no luck.

Comment: There's a typo.

Comment: @Marcello Romani Above mentioned code is just an example , just for people to get an idea of the problem and it’s not the actual code. I fixed the typo , thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I am not certain, but I think only the directories in `sys.path` are searched.  Maybe try adding `"imports"` to the `sys.path`? I'm very new at Python + Micropython, so maybe this is incorrect. The MP doc has a section on incompatibilities with standard Python...

Comment: @vishnujoshi :-) I didn't mean to be picky (my message didn't convey my intent), what I really meant is that perhaps you overlooked that typo and that's why you got the import error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Run` button stands for `Run current file`.
Therefore, only main.py is uploaded.
The import will fail because example.py is not uploaded.

Select `Pico-Go > Upload Project` from `All commands` for upload `example.py` to pico.
Then click `Run` and execute main.py, the import will be successful.

Environment

- vscode (1.65.2)
- Pico-Go (v1.4.3)

Comment: but it also then uploads .venv and other folders. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an empty `__init__.py` file in the `imports` directory, which would "magically" (by convention, actually) turn `imports` into a package.

https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/modules.html#packages

```
dir/
   main.py
   imports/
        __init__.py     # <= turns 'imports' into a package
        example.py
```

```
$ python main.py
name
```

Comment: But it was of no help. I already tried it and Im using micro python.

Comment: Have you tried this exact example? This is 100% standard Python. You should probably post your code then.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I have used micro python for raspberry pi pico where the code is uploaded using pico-go vscode extension. I am not executing the code through cli .

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately I don't own a Pico so unless you post the full code and command output I'm at a loss about what could be wrong. Good luck!  :-)

Comment: The example code itself throws that error.